# converting java date to oracle date format

Tags: java, oracle

i am having string as 10-07-1992. i have to convert this to oracle date format like         10-jul-1992. 
i tried using this

```
String date = fqu.getDob();

Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(date);

java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());

System.out.println("sql date"+sqlDate);
```

this prints like 1992-07-10. but this is not recognized while inserting this value in oracle.

i dont need to_cast method. this works only in sql command prompt. i want to do this conversion inside java file.

Answer (score 3):

Use Date format as dd-MMM-yyyy

```
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse(date);
```

Shows output as

```
10-jul-1992
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy").parse(date);
```